# recommended http response size

Tags: html, json

I am programming kind of social-network application and struggling with one particular decision. I have quite large json structure (300KB at least) for markers on a map and I wonder whether it is allright to render that into html or if I rather should use ajax to serve it by pieces. Is there any rule of thumb about recommended size of response (what is allright and what is already not)? Because the ajax solution on the other hand is more complicated and increases number of requests to my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's probably most important in your situation is perceived performance (how fast the site feels to the user).

I can't provide a rule of thumb on file size, but I can tell you that your average user gets impatient if a pages appears to take more than 500ms to load.

It might be best to load something (i.e. your map) quickly and then to use ajax requests to progressively add your pieces (geographic markers).  The improved perceived performance of things "loading" on the page as the user watches will outweigh the decrease in actual performance caused by making multiple calls to the server.  Otherwise, your user will be staring at a blank screen for the second or so that it takes to load the entire html file.

Comment: Well, ye I looked at youtube and similar pages and they all got response sizes <50KB. And in my case the rendering of that json structure prolongs time for about 0,5s. So I decided to do it by ajax as 300KB+ response seems unacceptable.